# Comparison of matching and 'normal' regression outcomes

Tags: regression, matching

As a form of sensitivity test, I want to compare the results from a regression model where I first conducted matching and the results from the same model without conducting matching prior to that. For the post-matching analysis, I used g-computation (using "avg_comparisons" in R) to get the treatment effect. Does it make sense to do the same for the regression model with the data that was not matched?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the point of matching is to be able to run the same analysis you would in the absence of matching but with the robustness added by matching. One important aspect is that you need to make sure the estimand is consistent across both methods; that means you must estimate the ATT using g-computation alone if you sought to estimate the ATT using matching. If you used a caliper in the matching, matching and regression alone target different estimands and any differences in the estimates could be due to that. To target the ATT using g-computation, subset the data in `avg_comparisons()`, as recommended in the `MatchIt` vignette.

Comment: Thank you so much! So would it be reasonable to use g-computation not only for the analysis that was preceded by matching but also for the same analysis where no matching was conducted prior to that? Or can/should g-computation only be used when matching was conducted prior to the analysis?

Comment: It should be used any time you want to estimate a treatment effect, whether matching was done or not. It is the only valid way to use regression to estimate treatment effects (the coefficient on treatment rarely corresponds to the desired estimand).